# Cannot execute SQL insert command using Python Dictionary as column value

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, databricks

I am utilizing Pyspark in Databricks including inserting parametrized values into a SQL Server table through a SQL command.

Inserting parameters into SQL command (Pyspark):

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Validation VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(app,date,anomaly,value)
```

The SQL Server table has the following columns:

```
app = [varchar](255)
date [date]
anomaly= [varchar](255)
value = [nvarchar](max)
```

Dictionary as shown below:

```
value = {'pt_PT.UTF-8': [88], 'lt_LT.UTF-8': [24], 'fi_FI.UTF-8': [4], 'fr_BE.UTF-8': [4], 'nl_NL.UTF-8': [4]}
```

Printed SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Validation VALUES ('TestApp','2020-05-06','LanguageAnomaly', '{'pt_PT.UTF-8': [88], 'lt_LT.UTF-8': [24], 'fi_FI.UTF-8': [4], 'fr_BE.UTF-8': [4], 'nl_NL.UTF-8': [4]}')
```

Error when executing SQL command:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   'pt_PT'.

The issue I am encountering seems to be related to inserting the dictionary parameter "value". This maybe related to the apostrophes within the dictionary keys which the code cannot properly parse as a whole string.

How can I resolve this? This seems to work find if the dictionary key is a number value/int without quotes(').

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with quotes from dictionary in your SQL insert statement, you need to escape them by doubling them up:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Validation VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(app,date,anomaly,str(value).replace("'", "''"))
```